# microstrain_3dmgx2_imu rosmake fail

Tags: ros, microstrain-3dmgx2-imu, rosmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am following tutorial from microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/Tutorials/UsingTheIMUNode

Trying to get my 3DM-GX3-25 to work

When i rosdep install microstrain_3dmgx2_imu everything is fine

when I do rosmake microstrain_3dmgx2_imu I get

### [rosmake-4] Starting >>> microstrain_3dmgx2_imu [ make ]
[ rosmake ] All 2 lines
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
mkdir: cannot create directory `build': Permission denied

[ rosmake ] Output from build of package microstrain_3dmgx2_imu written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/J/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130605-132831/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu/build_output.log
[rosmake-4] Finished <<< microstrain_3dmgx2_imu [FAIL] [ 0.06 seconds ]
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package microstrain_3dmgx2_imu.
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.
[ rosmake ] Results:
[ rosmake ] Built 38 packages with 1 failures.

When i tried to continue to the next step after plugging in the imu and typing  ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0

I get   ls: cannot access /dev/ttyUSB0: No such file or directory

Is my problem due to rosmake failing or is it the usb port problem or is it both?

I tried rosmake with root and it has no error but the directory is still not found o.O

I refered to the troubleshooting page for microstrain_3dmgx2_imu but my problem is not listed :(

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64337/microstrain_3dmgx2_imu-rosmake-fail/) by [Zoken](https://answers.ros.org/users/5059/zoken/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2013-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

FIXED!
i did sudo -s to rosmake microstrain_3dmgx2_imu
with no errors then
ls -l /dev/ttyACM0 instead of ls -l /dev/ttyUSB0
and everything work miracle

---

Originally posted by [Zoken](https://answers.ros.org/users/5059/zoken/) with karma: 16 on 2013-06-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0